# kinect SDK skeleton head cordinates

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm new to c#, wpf and the kinect SDK.

I have a project where I can track multiple skeletons.

Now I need to take a picture of the area around the users head. So I want to know where on the kinect's view field the top of the skeleton is located.

I don't want to use face tracking because I think its to complicated for the what I want to accomplish.

So is there an easy way to know where the head is located using only the skeleton? Preferably a set of coordinates where its located on the entire view field of the kinect.

thanks in advance!

Comment: which SDK Version are you using?

Comment: version 1.6, the latest I think

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx)?

Comment: yeah If been looking at it for a while now. Haven't found a way to extract the cordinates from the joints so I thought I'd ask here.

link to page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vector location = data.Joints[JointID.Head].Position;

If you need more context info for this line 
http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/hardware/3503-getting-started-with-microsoft-kinect-sdk-skeletons.html?start=1

Comment: But the Position in the Skeleton space is different to the head position in the camera space. You need to do a translation to get the head positon. Not sure how you would extract the head from the frame even after translating though

Comment: Not sure how to fix this, but i think this can help
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals

here they do some scaling to fix the poss (is implicit on code)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844585/mapping-an-ellipse-to-a-joint-in-kinect-sdk-1-5

Please Feedback so i can help